# Good Python programs for beginning CS student to write?

Tags: python

I plan on learning CS from my Python book before class starts (next semester though).

I am learning computer science from a Python Programming book. My question is, can I get some examples of good programs to write to begin learning programming? Once I finish the book, I want to start writing my own programs. I'm aware Python has a lot of power, but it's so versatile, not sure what it is I should try writing.

Preferably not something too advanced, but challenging enough to help me learn the building blocks of the language.

Comment: You can easily find most past year/term assignments online if you google "you_university_name course_name assignments". Try them and you can even find the lecture slides.

Comment: You are not learning computer science from that book, but only programming. CS is much nore than that.

Answer (score 7):

If you're interested in algorithmical and mathematical problems to solve, [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) has quite a few. At least a lot of other people have found them both entertaining and educational to solve, and Python is certainly a good language for the kind of problems.

Answer (score 2):

Google Code has a great coarse for python: [Google Code > Python Coarse](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/index.html)

It includes some exercise projects with descriptions of what to make and basic skeleton files, that make for good beginner projects: 
 [google-python-exercises.zip](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/google-python-exercises.zip)

You can also watch the videos of the class as it was presented to Google staff.
Search for: "Google Python Class Video"

I found these resources very helpful for learning python (just started 1 week ago). So far I've written a small command line HTTP client (with cookies) and a command line windows registry editor. Python is great, can't wait to start doing CGI with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try first to implement the most common algorithms in python. Try to search for good practices for implementing them in google. Try to implement them in functional and structured way (if applicable).

Actually http://www.python.org/community/ and the site itself has lots of good links.

Just go on and explore!

Comment: Thanks for the responses. @glglgl: The book is an intro to computer science and has a lot of mathematical programs. Besides, my goal isn't to learn every branch of CS, that doesn't make any sense. My goal is on CS concepts within the domain of programming/machine learning. :)